# Having trouble deploying Node with AWS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, devops

I’m trying to upload a Node.js backend to elastic beanstalk (AWS). Every time I try to upload and deploy my files I get the following error on the dashboard:

[errorlog1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmDbH.png)

In the logs it’s telling me that it can’t find my server.js file:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/var/app/current/server.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^
```

here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "bridal-book-db",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "knexfile.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "knex": "^0.15.2",
    "pg": "^7.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Hat-Factory/bridal-book-db.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Hat-Factory/bridal-book-db/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Hat-Factory/bridal-book-db#readme"
}
```

I’m really not sure what’s happening. I keep trying to change NPM packages and make sure my scripts are setup correctly, but no matter what I do the error persists.
What else can I provide here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Becci, welcome to S.O

Comment: Could you share the folder structure of your node project in the question? Also, this node app runs in your local environment?